# How can a researcher avoid socket vulnerabilities?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I need to use C# to have computers communicate across the net.  The net says to use sockets.

The net also says that there’s a lot of malicious folks out there who would love to mess up our work given half a chance, and that by opening ports, we’re giving them that half a chance.

What vulnerabilities are introduced by using sockets in .NET 4.5, C# on a Windows 7/8/Server 2012 machine, and how can these be best mitigated?

And what’s at stake?  Could opening a port really allow a malicious hacker to mess up our work?

Comment: IMO this is a somewhat broad and subjective question. Yes, allowing remote connections will always represent a risk. Your job as a developer is to mitigate the risk by including appropriate security measures. Sockets are opened all the time by all sorts of applications. The list of risks is virtually inexhaustable, so I don't really see a correct answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @jwd is mostly correct in what he says, there are numerous situations where the concept of limiting the access rights of the networked application - via sandboxing or other security layers - may not be either feasible or desirable.

The biggest problem with networked applications is how they handle (or *fail* to handle) malformed data in the network stream.  99% of the time (or thereabouts) this is because the developer who created the network code was lazy.  Period.

The holy grail of network hacks is remote code execution.  There are two primary methods that have been fairly successful in the past in this regard:

1. Traditionally the single biggest problem has been buffer overflows.
   When you're working with C#'s managed objects, this is less likely to be an issue.  You have to work pretty damn hard to make a C# application vulnerable to this type of attack.  We've come a long way since the good old days of static buffers on a single stack in C.
2. A close second is the problem of the various injection attacks.
   Read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Code Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) in general.  Always make absolutely certain that you are checking *every single value* that a user submits to your system, and if in doubt **always reject the problem message**.
3. File system access.
   Given access to arbitrary paths, an attacker may be able to upload a file to a location where it can be executed.  If you're allowing uploads, always make sure they can't go anywhere but a specific folder or set of folders.
4. And, of course, code execution by design.
   This is where your code is *designed* to allow remote code execution, but has not been secured adequately to restrict malicious content.  This is generally a bad idea anyway, but if you **must** allow this, make sure your security is as strong as you can make it.

After code execution, security breaches are the next big problem.  You can find numerous news stories of sensitive data being leaked through badly secured systems, and most of the time it's because the 'security' of the system was particularly poor.

End-to-end encryption - via SSL for instance - is a **must** whenever you are likely to transmit sensitive data... including user names and passwords.  A packet sniffer can monitor an unencrypted data stream and pull out login details.  Let's say you hash the actual sensitive login data... what happens if I use that exact hash value to login myself?

There are lots of problems like these, and you'll have to do a lot of reading before you get to grips with it all.  SQL injection attacks for instance can give you major headaches.

Finally, when all else fails, an attacker might settle for just taking down your system.  When your network code fails, make sure it will do so gracefully.

The morals of the story:

1. Link encryption (SSL or equivalent) is A Good Thing™
2. Check every piece of input and discard any connection that sends you bad data.
3. ***Always*** assume that your system will come under attack, and code accordingly.
4. Handle errors gracefully, or suffer the consequences.

Answer (score 3):

An open port is only as dangerous as the thing listening to it allows.

Usually, the weakest link is your application, not the underlying libraries.

It's certainly possible that there are problems in:

- Your OS's handling of networking
- The .NET framework's handling of networking

But mostly things get ugly when the malicious data gets to

- Your application

This last one, of course, depends entirely on the nature your application.

For instance, if you have an app that listens for arbitrary commands, such as running a program on the server, then the attacker could essentially do anything your application had permission to do - delete files, etc.

One way to mitigate risk is to give your applications very minimal permissions - at the OS level. That way the compromised app couldn't, say, delete system files.

Another way to mitigate risk is to run your app in a sandboxed environment, such as chroot or a FreeBSD jail. This is OS-dependent, as well.

In short, there are some things that can go wrong outside of your control (eg: an OS vulnerability), and there are other things, much more likely, that can go wrong with just your app. And there are some ways to mitigate that risk.

Comment: A big thing you have to watch for is making sure that data can't be sent to your application that will cause it to overflow a buffer - either directly (message bigger than expected) or indirectly (lie about the length of data in the message, or set the length impossibly high causing a crash, or...)

Comment: @Patashu It'd be nice to think that buffer overflows are a thing of the past, and with managed code engines like .NET this *should* be the case, but sadly it's still something that causes unending grief the world 'round.